# smalltalk method call with parameters

Tags: smalltalk

I wrote the following method in smalltalk:

```
initializeWithStart: startWith step: theStep count: theCount

self initialize.
startNumber := startWith.
stepSize := theStep.
countUntil := theCount.
```

and i just want to call this method after creating an object from the workspace. so I wrote:

```
mySq := ArithmeticsS new.
mySq initializeWithStart: '2' step:'4' count:'10'.
```

why do I get error "MessageNotUnderstood:undefinedobject>>initializeWithStart:step:count:"?

Comment: Looks like `ArithmeticsS new` returns `nil`. What is the super class of _ArithmeticsS_? Do you override `new` in _ArithmeticsS_

Comment: We probably need a bit more context here, as @Uko says

Comment: Also, are you sure, you executed both lines? One possibility is to select both lines and then „do“ them (from the context menu or via keyboard shortcut), or you „do“ them line by line. „print“ the first line, to see what you assign to the variable.

Comment: Also, is there instance method definition of initialize for ArithmeticsS class? If you did do both statements and got the error, then the initialize method returned nil (no ^ like your initializeWithStart:step:count that also returns nil)

Answer (score 1):

We can't say for sure without more context, but it looks like you created the new method on the class side, instead of the instance side.

In the workspace, you chose to send the message to an instance.

To find out, evaluate (print)

```
ArithmeticsS respondsTo: #initializeWithStart:step:count:
```

If the method is on the class side, that will be true. Delete that method and save it on the instance side instead.

Now evaluate

```
ArithmeticsS new respondsTo: #initializeWithStart:step:count:
```

With `new`, this checks for your method on the instance side. **It should be true.** My guess from the information you posted is that it is false, which means that you didn't save the method in the right place.

Check the documentation for your dialect of Smalltalk to confirm how to save an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate like this:

```
mySq := ArithmeticsS new initializeWithStart: 2 step:4 count:10.
```